# prevent duplicate objects being added to state react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a question regarding preventing duplicates from being added to my redux store.

It should be straight forward but for some reason nothing I try is working.

```
export const eventReducer = (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        case "ADD_EVENT":

            return [...state, action.event].filter(ev => {
                if(ev.event_id !== action.event.event_id){
                   return ev;
                }
            });


        default:
            return state;

    }

};
```

The `action` looks something like the below:

```
{
   type: "ADD_EVENT",
   event: { event_id: 1, name: "Chelsea v Arsenal" }
}
```

The issue is that on occasions the API I am working with is sending over identical messages through a websocket, which means that two identical events are getting added to my store.

I have taken many approaches but cannot figure out how to get this to work. I have tried many SO answers,

Comment: Adding what you have tried is the key point of not getting not useful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why your code is failing?

**Code:**

```
return [...state, action.event].filter(ev => {
    if(ev.event_id !== action.event.event_id){
       return ev;
    }
});
```

Because first you are adding the new element then filtering the **same element**, by this way it will never add the new value in the reducer state.

---

**Solution:**

Use [#array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to check whether item already exist in array or not if not then only add the element otherwise return the same state.

Write it like this:

```
case "ADD_EVENT":

    let index = state.findIndex(el => el.event_id == action.event.event_id);

    if(index == -1)
        return [...state, action.event];
    return state;
```

Comment: In my cart, I have an item and which one contains a quantity, I want if I add the same item to cart just increase the quantity `item1 => quantity x2` and avoiding duplicate

Comment: @DevAS in that case instead of using filter use map and keep checking for id, in case of true if condition increase the quantity otherwise return same item.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

**Example** *(Not tested)*

```
const eventExists = (events, event) => {
  return evets.find((e) => e.event_id === event.event_id);
}
export const eventReducer = (state = [], action) = > {
    switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_EVENT":
      if (eventExists(state, action.event)) {
        return state;
      } else {
        return [...state, action.event];
      }
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

**Update** *(@CodingIntrigue's comment)*

You can also use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for a better approach

```
const eventExists = (events, event) => {
  return evets.some((e) => e.event_id === event.event_id);
}
export const eventReducer = (state = [], action) = > {
    switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_EVENT":
      if (eventExists(state, action.event)) {
        return state;
      } else {
        return [...state, action.event];
      }
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is the approach I'd take. Except I'd replace `find` with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: @CodingIntrigue thank you for the addition. I updated the answer.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Could you please explain why ``some`` should be used over ``find``?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
const eventReducer = ( state = [], action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_EVENT':
            return state.some(( { event_id } ) => event_id === action.event.event_id)
                ? state
                : [...state, action.event];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Test:

```
const state1 = eventReducer([], {
    type: 'ADD_EVENT',
    event: { event_id: 1, name: 'Chelsea v Arsenal' }
});

const state2 = eventReducer(state1, {
    type: 'ADD_EVENT',
    event: { event_id: 2, name: 'Chelsea v Manchester' }
});

const state3 = eventReducer(state2, {
    type: 'ADD_EVENT',
    event: { event_id: 1, name: 'Chelsea v Arsenal' }
});

console.log(state1, state2, state3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this, for the logic part to ensure you don't get the same entry twice.

```
const x = filter.arrayOfData(item => item.event_id !== EVENT_FROM_SOCKET);
if (x.length === 0) {
  // dispatch action here
} else {
  // ignore and do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when using Arrays in reducers. You are essentially adding more items to the list when you call:

```
[...state, action.event]
```

If you instead use a map then you can prevent duplicates

```
const events = { ...state.events }
events[action.event.event_id] = action.event.name]
{...state, events }
```

Comment: ok, where have you used map here though? and I thought the spread operator doesnt mutate the array? also this answer seems to suggest this is how you would update the array - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932742/redux-how-to-add-entry-to-array-in-reducer

Answer (score 0):

If duplicate exist in previous state then we should return same state else update the state

```
case "ADDPREVIEW":
     let index = state.preview.findIndex(dup => dup.id == action.payload.id);
     return {
             ...state,
             preview: index == -1 ? [...state.preview,action.payload]:[...state.preview]
     };
```